# Can the coin symbol prefix in a cloned NXT blockchain start with a digit?

Tags: alternatives, nxt

Creating a new blockchain with the Nxt Blockchain Creation Kit, is it possible to use a coin symbol prefix beginning with a digit in the wallet address?

I get an error that the address is malformed when I try this. Should I look for an error, or is this impossible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to Bitcoin.

Comment: Please provide the prefix you try and the error

Comment: Error: "The recipient address is malformed." The prefix would reveal the project prematurely...

Answer (score 3):

No, adding a coin symbol prefix is not doable as it will impact other functions that might take it as a parameter. Your better off just doing it on the front end using a css :before class using the **content:** property.

Comment: We discovered that we could add the prefix by editing the Constants.java file.

Answer (score 2):

It should be OK for the prefix to start with digit. Or at least this works for me in `Constants.java`:

```
public static final String COIN_SYMBOL = "5Coin";
public static final String ACCOUNT_PREFIX = "5CN";
public static final String PROJECT_NAME = "5Coin";
```

Now accounts look like `5CN-P6F5-J7VU-RWHZ-9LXN8` and the coin name as displayed in UI is `5Coin`.

Comment: Thanks, we got it to appear in the UI, the error appeared when we tried to send funds. Error: "The recipient address is malformed."